# Giving a bound to an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

$I_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{n}e^{x-1}dx$

Show:

$0 < I_{n} < \frac{1}{n+1}$

The lower bound is obvious but my attempts to get an upper bound have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $0 < x <1$ note that $x^{n}e^{x-1} < x^{n}$ and if $f < g$ then $\int f < \int g$